# Groovy- map : every time require new instance

Tags: grails, groovy, hashmap

My requirement is to get a NEW instance every time when I access the value in a MAP.

```
MyObject {
    def type
}


def myMap = [
"key1" : new MyObject()
]

def obj1 =  myMap.get("key1")
def obj2 =  myMap.get("key1")
```

Can *obj1* and *obj2* be two different instances? 
How will it behave if executed/accessed parallelly?

Comment: Reading your question, it is unclear to me, whether you want the same object every time, or instantiate a new object every time, as you first state you want a new one every time, but, after your code, ask whether they can be the same every time. Could you please clarify that with an edit?

Comment: To add clarity, I want to instantiate a new object every time. Thx

Comment: Why bother with the map if the value changes every time?

Comment: It's existing implementation and trying to understand one problem related to parallel runs.

Comment: create a getter to return a clone of the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know what your use case is, but I guess I have the answer to your question:

```
def myMap = [
  "key1" : new MyObject()
]
```

Just first instantiates a new object and then stores this object in the map. So every time you access it, you get the same object.

To create the behavior you describe, you need to add something dynamic to your map - a closure!

```
def myMap = [
  "key2" : {-> new MyObject()}
]
```

but now a `myMap.get("key2")` still returns always the same - a closure. But if you execute it by calling `myMap.get("key2")()` (or short `myMap.key2`) you get a different object each time!

Unfortunately, this is a close as you will get. I hoped to do a trick with a key called `getKey3` - I hoped that Groovy would call this "getter" when accessing `key3` but this seems not to be the case.

There are other "tricks" in Groovy which could help you to achieve your goal (like MetaProgramming) but I guess there is a better solution if we would know your use case.

Comment: Let me try it out and confirm back.